# Helper’s UK visa refused

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I have just received a refusal from uk embassy in Philippines for my helpers visit to the uk with me and my 3 kids later this month.  I am travelling on my own with my kids, 7, 3 and 1 and will need some support on the flight especially.

I applied for the worker in a foreign household visa, but one of the criteria is she needs to have worked for me for 1 year.  I assumed (incorrectly) that this was based on the visa dates (my dates of travel - so 27th June) and not application date.

I was wrong.  $1,400 later (for fast track service and visa fee) I received the rejection letter - ironically I received this on the day when she celebrated her 1 year anniversary with my family.  We basically applied 5 days too early.

This seems like gross tick-boxing to me.  I appreciate rules is rules, but really, does the British embassy have no ability to see that she would have worked with my fam for 1 year literally on the day they reject her visa.

My confusion came about as on the website the eligibility criteria reads:

1. have worked for your employer for at least 1 year
   work in the same household as your employer or one they use regularly
2. plan to travel to the UK with your employer, their partner or children
3. plan to leave the UK at the end of 6 months or at the same time as your employer, whichever is sooner

When I read these 3 points together, I presumed this was based on time of travel.  If only they include the words ‘at the time of application’ I would have known to wait a few days before applying.

I am now petrefied that if I apply again they will find another reason to reject her visa, costing me the same again.

The sad thing is she’s amazing, and was so excited to visit the uk and see my wider family, who she has met and gets on with really well.

Any similar experience / do you think I will get a visa if I reapply?  The 1 year part was the only reason given for her rejection.

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect one issue here is that the fast track priority service [may not be of use if the applicant has previously been refused a visa](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/ca/en/sitecore/content/vfs_uk/philippines/home/premium-services/super-priority-visa), so you could end up paying for the priority service and receiving no benefit from it (they say no refunds are offered) over the standard processing time.

Comment: Thank you.  Yep, that’s for the Super priority service - which excludes domestic workers anyway.  The one I did last time was the 5 day fast track.  I will look at the detail to see if it will not apply to her since she was refused the first time.  Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about your bad experience. Do note that bending the rules because it was only five days immediately opens them up to having to bend the rules if it's only ten days -- if the _de facto_ rule becomes "Must have worked with you for 360 days" then somebody will just say "But 355 days is only a few days less than your effective limit, so you should bend the new rules for me."

Comment: Visa applications are decided on their own merit; we can't do anything more than speculate about whether your application would be successful.